# Ошибка "selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: variable is not defined" Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

У меня есть скрипт, где я запрашиваю текст у пользователя, после чего селениум должен этот текст вставить в элемент:

```
NewName = input("")
time.sleep(1)
element =  driver.find_element_by_class_name("style-scope ytd-channel-name")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = (NewName);", element)
```

Но, когда я выполняю его, мне выдаёт эту ошибку:

`selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: NewName is not defined`

Я так понимаю, в самом джава скрипте нет этой переменной, но как мне её туда засунуть?
Я уже искал решения, но не нашёл похожие ситуации.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```py
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = arguments[1];", element, NewName)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!